# Changing the name of a list on the fly using a counter

Tags: list

I have a set of list,

```
    list_0=[a,b,a,b,b,c,f,h................] 
    list_1=[f,g,c,g,f,a,b,b,b,.............] 
    list_2=[...............................]
    ............ 
    list_j=[...............................]
```

where j is (k-1), with some thousands of value stored in them. I want to count for how many times a specific value is in a specific list. And I can have only 8 different values (I mean, every single element of those list can only have one out of 8 specific values, let's say a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h; so I want to count for every list how many times there's the value a, how many times the value b, and so on).
This is not so complicated.
What is complicated, at least for me, is to change on the fly the name of the  list.
I tried:

```
    for i in range(k):
        my_list='list_'+str(int(k))
        a_sum=exec(my_list.count(a))
        b_sum=exec(my_list.count(b))
        ...
```

and it doesn't work.
I've read some other answer to similar problem, but I' not able to translate it to fit my need :-(
Tkx.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to dynamically access a local variable by its name. That's doable, all you need is `locals()`.

If you have variables with names "var0", "var1" and "var2", but you want to access their content without hardcoding it. You can do it as follows:

```py
var0 = [1,2,3]
var1 = [4,5,6]
var2 = [7,8,9]
for i in range(3):
  variable = locals()['var'+str(i)]
  print(variable)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Although doable, it's not advised to do this, you could store those lists in a dict containing their names as string keys, so that later you could access them by simply using a string without needing to take care about variable scopes.

If your names differ just by a number then perhaps you could also use a list, and the number would be the index inside it.